# How to finish the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sinh(x)}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, digamma-function

I was evaluating:

$$I:=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sinh(x)}\,dx$$

This is what I did, how can my answer be simplified if correct. The following is my work:

$$I=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{e^x-e^{-x}}\,dx$$

$$=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}\sin(x)}{1-e^{-2x}}\,dx$$

$$=2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\sin(x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-2xn}\,dx$$

$$=-2\Im\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(2n+1+i)x}\,dx$$

$$=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2+1}$$

$$=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2+1}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+\alpha}-\frac{1}{n+\beta}$$

$$\alpha:=-\frac{1+i}{2},\beta:=\frac{i-1}{2}$$

Adding and subtracting $\frac{1}{n}$ yields:

$$I=\frac{1}{2i}[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+\beta}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+\alpha}]$$

$$I=\frac{1}{2i}(\psi(\beta)-\psi(\alpha))$$

And so

$$I=\frac{1}{2i}(\psi(\frac{i-1}{2})-\psi(-\frac{i+1}{2}))$$

I found a YouTube video on this integral where it was correctly evaluated to be $\frac{\pi}{2}\tanh(\frac{\pi}{2})$

Can I get some guidance on simplifying the digamma functions so as to get the given answer. Also if I made any mistakes I would like corrections to them please.

Thank you for your help!

Edit (1):

We can use the following digamma properties namely:

$$\psi(1-x)-\psi(x)=\pi\cot(\pi x)$$

$$\psi(1+x)-\psi(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$

Using these we can see that:

$$\psi(-\frac{1+i}{2})=\frac{2}{1+i}+\psi(\frac{1-i}{2})$$

$$\psi(\frac{i-1}{2})=\frac{2}{1-i}-\pi\cot(\frac{\pi}{2}(1+i))+\psi(\frac{1-i}{2})$$

Doing the arithmetic we obtain a new expression for $I$.

$$I=1+\frac{\pi}{2}\tanh(\frac{\pi}{2})$$

New question: why is the $+1$ there? I can’t seem to figure out how it got there but it is the only thing left causing problems. Any help is appreciated!

Edit (2): I solved it! Here is what I did wrong and how I fixed it:

$$I=\frac{1}{2i}[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+\beta}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+\alpha}]$$

$$I=\frac{1}{2i}(\psi(\beta+1)-\psi(\alpha+1))$$

$$I=\frac{1}{2i}(\psi(\frac{i+1}{2})-\psi(\frac{1-i}{2}))$$

Then from the aforementioned formula we can see that:

$$\psi(\frac{1-i}{2})=\psi(\frac{1+i}{2})-\pi\cot(\frac{\pi}{2}(1-i))$$

And so doing the arithmetic we get:

$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}\tanh(\frac{\pi}{2})$$

Comment: The second to the third line is incorrect

Comment: @NinadMunshi I didn’t put a negative where it should have been it is edited accordingly now.

Comment: compare the 6th line in your attempt, with the last given formula for $\tanh(x)$ evaluated at $x=\frac{π}{2}$ given by wolframalpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=taylor+series+tanh%28x%29

Comment: You can't interchange summation and integration like that, you're getting a divergent series (look at the real parts instead, their series diverges).